How to count and return number occurrences of randomly chosen words from a list in python?
I can't import anything else other than random. The goal is to create a list from a dictionary where the values of the keys indicates how many times the word(key) will appear in the list. Then from this list, randomly chose a word and return the number of times each word was chosen.
The desired return values are 100, 300, 200 respectively. I keep getting return values of all zero.
import random 
def weighted_choice(counts):
    list = []
    for key in counts.keys():
        n = counts[key]
        for i in range(n):
            list.append(key)
    choice = random.choice(list)
    occurances = []
    occurances.append(choice)
    counter = occurances.count(choice)
    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    for i in range(600):
        item = weighted_choice({'green': 1, 'eggs': 3, 'ham':2})
        results.append(item)
    print(results.count('green')) #about 100
    print(results.count('eggs')) #about 300
    print(results.count('ham')) #about 200


Simplify: for key, n in counts.items():

Have you checked what counter is when you return counter?

list.extend([key] * n) instead of the loop.

occurrences only has one element. So occurrences.count(choice) will always be 1.

Why don't you just return choice? What is all that occurrence stuff for?

If you're allowed to import random, can't you use the weights option to random.choices()?

What debugging did you do? Surely you would have noticed the problem if you did print(item) or print(results)

Barmar, thank you!! You were right. I didn't need all the occurences. I had the random.choice in the wrong for loop. I deleted the three lines after choice = and moved that into the second for loop, then returned choice. boom.

This is where you need to use random.choices() function.
import random 

dictionary = {'green': 1, 'eggs': 3, 'ham':2}
words   = list(dictionary.keys())
weights = list(dictionary.values())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    for i in range(600):
        item = random.choices(words,weights)[0]
        results.append(item)
    print(results.count('green')) #about 100
    print(results.count('eggs')) #about 300
    print(results.count('ham')) #about 200

According to the documentation of random.choices, it takes these parameters as input :

population   : a sequence to select random from
weights      : the weights for the selection of items
cum_weights  : cumulative weights
k            : the number of items to choose


So, you can rewrite your code in this way :
import random 

dictionary = {'green': 1, 'eggs': 3, 'ham':2}
words   = list(dictionary.keys())
weights = list(dictionary.values())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = random.choices(words,weights,k=600)
    print(results.count('green')) #about 100
    print(results.count('eggs')) #about 300
    print(results.count('ham')) #about 200

